# PostgreSQL While Function

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am new in PostgreSQL. I have the following code (Stored Procedure) in SQL Server:

```
Create function sp_test as
Begin 

 declare @cont int
 set @cont = 0
 while (@cont<5)

 Begin 
   if @cont < 3
   print ('Hola Charly' + cast (@cont as varchar))

   else
   print ('Hello Friends' + cast (@cont as varchar))

   set @cont = @cont + 1
 end
End
```

I want to make the same as I did using SQL Sever but now through PostgreSQL.
I have tried the following but I have not been able to run it so far:

```
   CREATE function sp_test () returns void as $$ 
DECLARE 
    cont int=0;

BEGIN 

  while cont<5
  LOOP

   IF (cont < 3)
   THEN
   RAISE NOTICE 'Hola Charly %', cont;
   -- + cast (cont as varchar))

   else
   RAISE NOTICE 'Hello friends %', cont; 
   -- print ('Hello Friends' + cast (cont as varchar))

   END IF;

   cont:= cont + 1;

  END LOOP;


RETURN;   
END;   
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My first doubt is:

How can I do to see the results?

I have tried with:

```
SELECT sp_test();
```

But I just get the following output:

[image: Output of Function]

Thanks for your time & support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking into the wrong Tab. I clicked on Messages Tab and I saw what I wanted.

[image: Correct output]

Thanks anyway!